# Heremap AndroidXMapFragment back press handling

Tags: android, android-fragments, here-api, heremaps, heremaps-android-sdk

I work with HERE map Android SDK and with its AndroidXMapFragment.
I add map fragment to my fragment container in the next way:

```
appActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragment_container, hereMapFragment, TAG)
            .addToBackStack(TAG)
            .commit();
```

But when back press action happens, I get an empty fragment, without map and objects in it.
So, question is: How I should process back press and should I recreate AndroidXMapFragment manually?
In documentation the only thing I found is:

> AndroidXMapFragment objects have their own lifecycle, state, and back stack, thus it is unsafe to assume objects returned by a AndroidXMapFragment instance (with the exception of Map) will be available throughout the lifetime of its attached activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer on the question after trying different approaches.
So the answer is:
If you have to use fragment-based architecture of your app, you should handle back press manually and recreate AndroidXMapFragment and initialize it again with parameters you have.
In this case you should use:

```
appActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, searchLocationFragment, TAG)
                .commit();
```

without addToBackStack method. And also for handling back press use Activity's override method:

```
@Override public void onBackPressed() {
        Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
        AppController.instance(this).onBackPressed(fragment);
}
```

But if there are no need to keep fragment-based architecture, I'd recommend to use the **latest sdk**. There is a MapView, which you can use instead of AndroidXMapFragment.